# Is there an implementation of infinite scroll with useEffect that doesn't trigger the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps lint warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm implementing an infinite scroll-like solution using React hooks. The following code shows what I'm trying to accomplish and a working example can be seen on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-taussig-o93er).

I'm receiving an `exhaustive-deps` warning in `useEffect` because I haven't listed `data` as a dependency (this would obviously cause an infinite loop). Is there a way to implement this kind of infinite scrolling solution without suppressing this warning?

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = getData(page);
    setData([...data, ...newData]);
  }, [page, setData]); // react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning here

  return (
    <div>
      Data:
      <ul>
        {data.map(el => (
          <li>{el}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Load More</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [pass a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to receive the previous data.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = getData(page);
    setData(previousData => [...previousData, ...newData]);
  }, [page, setData]);
```

Forked sandbox without warnings.
[image: Edit so.answer.57564952]

---

Unrelated to the warning above, also make sure to add `key` prop for each item.

```
 <li key={el}>{el}</li>
```

Comment: My hero. I can't accept this for 5 minutes but will be doing so soon.

Comment:  High-five Thank you @Nick~